# Is Ray Wise's character in Fargo Season 3 real or the character's imagination?

Tags: fargo-tv

Ray Wise plays a recurring role in Fargo season 3, the two scenes to point out is when he meets Gloria on the plane to L.A. and when he speaks with Nikki at the bowling alley and helps her out with a vehicle to get away in.  I am curious to know if he actually exists or if he is their imagination.  An explanation on what his character represents.

Comment: I believe he was meant to be the legendary mythical figure Wandering Jew, but I'm still looking for a good source before I make an answer...